# Bootstrap modal fade in effect not working properly

Tags: jquery, button, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm trying to get the modal of Bootstrap to `fade in` and `fade out` when the modal is opened or closed. The problem is that it only works the first time I open the modal by using the button in the code below. After that it closes with the regular `fade` effect instead of the `fade in` effect. 
It seems that either the open function or the close function of the modal of the Bootstrap framework removes the `in` class of the modal div (in my case `login`). So if I reopen the modal again, it uses the regular `fade` effect since the `in` class is missing.

The code for the button:

```
<a href="#login" role="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal">Login</a>
```

The modal div.

```
<div id="login" class="modal hide fade in">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h3><spring:message code="login.dialog.title" /></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        blaat
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see what the problem is: http://jsfiddle.net/jdwire/9JnWN/

Comment: @JoshuaDwire if you open the modal the first time, it uses the fade in effect. If you press the close button it uses the regular fade effect (if you use firebug on the modal you'll see that the "in" class has been removed). This means that the fade effect is used rather then the fade in effect. I want to have the fade in effect permanent instead of just the first time the modal is opened.

Also, I would like to have a fade out effect on close, which I assumed would work as long as the div login would have the fade in class.

Comment: @JaapOudejans remove the `in` and test

Comment: @PiLHA if I do that, then I would get the regular fade effect(which makes the modal slide down from the top). But when the `in` class is added, the modal will appear from the center of the screen. (Look at @JoshuaDwire jsfiddle url to see what I mean; if you run it for the first time it appears from the center of the screen, much like a fade in effect, whereas closing and reopening the modal, it will slide down from the top).

What I want is a fade in and fade out effect on the modal much like a jQuery modal (http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form)